# Loop over table and call stored procedure

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, cursor

Right now, i am trying to loop over a temporary table, that an import process created. I've tried using a cursor, but the tablename must be passed to the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `do_update`(tablename VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE c_ean VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE c_sku VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE c_mpn VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE c_manufacturerName VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE c_manufacturerUniqueId VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE c_images TEXT;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;
    -- move declare cursor into sql to be executed
    SET @sqlstatement = CONCAT('DECLARE import_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ean, sku, mpn, manufacturerName, manufacturerUniqueId, images FROM ', tablename);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstatement;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;    

    OPEN import_cursor;
    importloop: LOOP
        FETCH import_cursor INTO c_ean, c_sku, c_mpn, c_manufacturerName, c_manufacturerUniqueId, c_images;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE importloop;
        END IF;
        CALL upsert_article(c_ean, c_sku, c_mpn, c_manufacturerName, c_manufacturerUniqueId, c_images);
    END LOOP testloop;
    CLOSE import_cursor;
END
```

*Note: This import script will be called several times over the day and could be run concurrently. So a defined tablename is not an option.*

What i have tried so far:

1. Creating a cursor with given tablename. --> Works, but the name must be dynamic.
2. Creating a cursor with dynamic sql. --> Failed
3. Skip using cursors and loop over table in a different way. --> No method found for using dynamic sql

So, is there a way to make this work with a cursor or a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a temporary table and inserting the results of my dynamic query did the trick at the end. 
With that i was able to use mysql cursor with the static named temporary table. And since it is an temporary table, multiple import-jobs won't interfere with each other, because they are hidden to other sessions.

In the end this is the code, that worked for me:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `do_update`(IN 

tablename VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT;

    DECLARE c_ean VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE c_sku VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE c_mpn VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE c_manufacturerName VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE c_manufacturerUniqueId VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE c_images NVARCHAR(3000);
    DECLARE import_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ean, sku, mpn, manufacturerName, manufacturerUniqueId, images FROM importjob;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS importjob;

    SET @sqlstatement = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE importjob SELECT ean, sku, mpn, manufacturerName, manufacturerUniqueId, images FROM ', tablename);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstatement;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SET @DEBUG = true;

    OPEN import_cursor;
    importloop: LOOP
        FETCH import_cursor INTO c_ean, c_sku, c_mpn, c_manufacturerName, c_manufacturerUniqueId, c_images;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE importloop;
        END IF;
        CALL upsert_article(c_ean, c_sku, c_mpn, c_manufacturerName, c_manufacturerUniqueId, c_images);
    END LOOP importloop;
    CLOSE import_cursor;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS importjob;
END
```